# Thread running in background returns strings to handler of whatever current activity

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, background-service

I am trying to receive messages in current activity instead of just `MainActivity`
**background service:**
                `MainActivity.bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();`
**MainActivity:**
here is handler which receive messages from background service.
now what I am trying to do is how to make able all activities which I want to revieve messages from this  background service. any help will be really appreciated.
`'currentActivity'.bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();`

Comment: Make one class which extends application and start service from that class and get instance of that class into all other class.

Comment: @AkashDubey can you Please post it as a complete answer so that I can accept, with more explanation . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly make this class,

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
MyService myService;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    myService = new MyService(this);
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(getCtx(), myService.getClass());
    }
}
public Context getCtx() {
    return ctx = this;
}
```

and receive the message in all activities like wise MainActivity